# Processing unorder lists PHP-HTML

Tags: php, html, xml, html-lists

Good afternoon.

I have a page that looks like this 
                **-edit-** It is important to note that the  code is DYNAMIC. My users are uploading these pictures, then through an echo, a new list object is created with the img code inside. I cannot "hard code" because the lists will NEVER be the same.  I will have clients uploading 50+ pictures, so they will have 50+ list items. What I want to be able to do is fine a way turn that list that I create into a string - Or I am open to other suggestions.

```
<ul>
<li class="ui-state-default"><img code for img 1></li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><img code 2></li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><img code 3></li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><img code 4></li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><img code 5></li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><img code 6></li>
<li class="ui-state-default"><img code 7></li>
</ul>
```

What I would like to do is find a way to process this list in the correct order through PHP.

I.E  Create an XML from that list.

I am familiar with SimpleXML, but am having a hard time figuring out to get PHP to see the list. My question is how - How can I get PHP read that list, so I can create a xml of it?

I have tried several Ajax examples, Ajax is just to complicated when it to this from the examples I've seen.

Thank you for any assistance you can provide, please do not leave comments only saying "Use DOM" and not explaining further.  Ive had way to many of those.

edit ------------

My last attempt was this

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($data);
$unorderedList = $dom->getElementsByTagName('ul');
foreach ($unorderedList->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('li') as $unorderedList) {
    echo $unorderedList->nodeValue.'<br />';                    
}
?>
```

but, I am unable to get PHP to be able to see the list...My question really revolves around how to get PHP to see the list in the HTML above it (same page) not how to create the xml.

Comment: Can you tell us what have you tried ?

Comment: "Process a list" is a pretty vague. What are you trying to do precisely, and why hasn't SimpleXML worked for you?

Comment: I just edited, maybe that will shed some light.

Comment: So in your example, what is `$data`? It's still unclear where you're trying to fetch the HTML from.

Comment: I guess that is what I am asking - How do I pull the list above my php code into a format that PHP can understand.

Comment: You could just make it a string if you wanted and hard code it into your PHP. Is there a specific place you need to pull it from?

Comment: Ahh, I see where I miscommunicated here. Let me edit once agian.

Comment: edited it once more. This may shed some light.

Comment: If you're the one generating the list, why do you need to parse the HTML? Aren't you the one generating the HTML? It seems like whatever your problem is, there's a much more direct solution than doing HTML parsing in PHP.

Comment: I would do it on my side, however the list is part of a drag and drop system, the user can rearrange the lists using JqueryUI, so I need to be able to pull the list as it is at that moment. I will admit I left out alot more than I should have in my question

Comment: @RobertDickey: if you need an order of elements which are manipulated by javascript, it might be more efficient to define some property (preferably `data-` ones) on the sorted elements itself, and only sent that order back as an array or json (`[id1,id2,id4,id3,id6,id7]`). Less overhead, less room for error and/or abuse, more efficient overall in my opinion, but it's debatable.

Comment: hint: use xpath, it's often more expressive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping over all `<li>` elements but are looking for the image tags. So you need to go a level deeper

```
if ($unorderedList->hasChildNodes()) {
    foreach ($unorderedList->childNodes as $image) {
        var_dump($image->getAttribute('src'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the `as $varname` something different then your main variable, `$unorderedList->nodeValue` is just empty (no text node content, I admit that property is [badly documented](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.nodevalue) *"The value of this node, depending on its type"* says nothing), it will output:

```
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
```

If you want the html of that content:

```
foreach ($unorderedList->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('li') as $listItem) {
    foreach($listItem->childNodes as $node){
        echo $dom->saveHTML($node);//use $dom->saveXML($node) if in PHP < 5.3.6
    }
    echo '<br />';                    
}
```

Comment: I tried this (simple copy and paste) and did not receive any output. It is possible I am missing something though. I have ZERO experience with DOM.

Comment: [here you can see it NOT working in PHP < 5.3.6](http://codepad.org/uVFxMF9s), [and here you can see this exact code working with the suggested `->saveXML($node);` for PHP < 5.3.6](http://codepad.org/ANHPlAJr) (for some reason codepad [runs `5.2.5`](http://codepad.org/v7rdFrLg)